# PostHog: Only show the first 5 properties of a single event

Tags: posthog

I had a insight in Posthog that shows "️ produto acessado!" (product accessed) and it has the property produto (product) and categoria (category), and im showing the event and breaking down my product, but i wanna show only the 5 more accessed products, how can i do that? i tried many things but i didint find how to do this.

[image]

Comment: I have the opposite problem. By default PostHog only shows the first 5 values of a series and I have to manually check all the others each time I want to see them.